# How can i call child's static method from parent's static method?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a Base class

```
public class BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "Base";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    public static void send(){
        System.out.println("BaseStatic send");
        sendTo();
    }

    public static void sendTo(){
        //How to call from here Child's static method.
        System.out.println("BaseStatic sendTo");
    }
}
```

and I have a Child Class which extends it.

```
public class FirstStatic extends BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "First";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    public static void sendTo(){
        System.out.println("FirstStatic sendTo");
    }
}
```

Now there is an Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FirstStatic.send();
    }
}
```

Does java provide me a way so that when i call from Main method FirstStatic.send , It goes to send method of BaseStatic , from there i can call sendTo method of FirstStatic rather than calling sendTo method of BaseStatic

Comment: My FirstStatic class doesn't want to right its own send method so want to use , but the problem is it is mandatory to call sendTo method from send method . Now either i should write an method send in FirstStatic also , or i should have some way to call FirstStatic.sendTo from send method of BaseStatic

Comment: you mean send method ? because sendTo method is already in the FirstStatic.

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do with `static` methods. Why do these methods have to be `static` anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no polymorphism for static methods. Therefore, in order to call a static method `x` of class `A`, you must write `A.x()`.

`FirstStatic.send()` will call `BaseStatic`'s `send` only because `FirstStatic` has no static `send` method. However, `BaseStatic`'s `send` will always call `BaseStatic`'s `sendTo`, unless you explicitly call `FirstStatic.sendTo()`.

Comment: see when i make a call FirstStatic.send or BaseStatic.send while going in send method , can there be a way by which i can figure out the class name from which this method has been called.

Comment: @AdonSmith No. As long as FirstStatic has no `send` method, both calls are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The commented-out sendTo() method here would have the effect of hiding the implementation of sendTo() in the base class.

```
public class BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "Base";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    public static void send(){
        System.out.println("BaseStatic send");
        sendTo();
    }

    public static void sendTo(){
        //How to call from here Child's static method.
        System.out.println("BaseStatic sendTo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstStatic.sendTo();
    }
}

class FirstStatic extends BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "First";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    //public static void sendTo(){
    //    System.out.println("FirstStatic sendTo");
    //}
}
```

You can do the following, of course, but the net effect is identical to the code shown above. If you need polymorphism, you'll need to do away with the statics--probably a good idea, anyway!

```
public class BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "Base";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    public static void send(){
        System.out.println("BaseStatic send");
        sendTo();
    }

    public static void sendTo(){
        //How to call from here Child's static method.
        System.out.println("BaseStatic sendTo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstStatic.sendTo();
    }
}

class FirstStatic extends BaseStatic {
    public static String fname = "First";
    public static String lname = "Static";

    public static void sendTo(){
        BaseStatic.sendTo();
    }
}
```

EDIT: These examples are structured such that you can easily do the following to verify the behavior.

```
javac BaseStatic.java
java BaseStatic
```